# Asterisk not working in for loops

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am building code. I can't seem to get the asterisks in the for loop "*.map" to work? Any reason for this? Is it because they are `for` loops inside a `findstr` inside another `for` loop?

Thanks!

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%A in (Marks.txt) do (
  set var1=!var1!%%A

  findstr /e "!var1!" "*.map" 

  if not errorlevel 1 (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==,." %%B in ('findstr /e "!var1!" *.map') do (
      set var2=!var2!%%B

      set /a linecount+=1
      if !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO part2
    )

:part2
    for /f "tokens=4 delims==,." %%C in ('findstr /e "!var1!" *.map') do (
      set var3=!var3!%%C
      if !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO exitloop
    )
  )
```

Comment: Please show `Marks.txt`.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve? What is the result you expect, and how is it different from the result you get?

Comment: the "*.map" in the 2 for loops are not working. The findstr "*.map" is working though.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing paren

Comment: I was missing a closing paren but that didn't fix it. Thanks.